# Making an Image Stay in the Same Place on a Background

Tags: html, css

So I have an image and a background on a website page made with Elementor.
I tried using Cruely Slider in order to make it stay in the same position and it worked, however I'm unable to code the image this way (I want to make it clickable and open an overlay with a form).

If I set the background with HTML and add the image I'm unable to make the image stay in the same place without changing it's position when is resized. You can see it at the bottom of this page: [www.walterbar.co.il](http://www.waterbar.co.il) You can also see the slider I've made at the top of the page. I apologize for the weird language.

Any ideas how I can place the potion thingy on the shelf just like I did in the slider? And how to make it responsive? I'm not so good with coding but I'm trying my best.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey Rozi, please provide a [mcve] within your question (preferably as a Stack Snippet) instead of linking to an external website. Also check [ask].

Comment: Hey Dom, Thanks. Is it forbidden to use external links? I wanted to show what it looks like with a slider plug-in and how it looks without it.

Comment: Not strictly forbidden, but: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it